# HTML5 Canvas as a background

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, canvas

I am currently designing a site that uses canvas to draw and animate moving stars as the background. It looks good but I have some concerns about performance.

At the moment it falls back to a flat background if it's any version of IE (as even though IE9 + 10 support canvas - it slows them down a bit), and the same for mobile / any other browser that doesn't support canvas.

It runs fine on latest chrome/firefox/safari + opera in my particular setup but I have no idea whether or not this will land someone with a decent browser but a poor performance computer having trouble using the site.

Comment: Can you show it to us? It's probably not a good idea. Besides poor performance, continuous animations usually annoy site visitors

Comment: This is going to be a big factor on mobile devices as well. Their webkit browsers can do canvas but the performance is usually very bad

Comment: @onetrickpony - it's subtle, which is why I thought that performance wasn't going to be an issue, here's a link to an example of just the background: http://www.accountancyaction.com/testFolder/teststars.php.

Comment: @JaniHartikainen we're having a separate mobile site, tablets will display this background though - although I could specify view ports suggesting tablet devices display the flat background instead. In that case would it be safe to go ahead?

Comment: I think it's fine to use it.. why not? if it's missbehaving you can remove them... :) .. In my opinion this shouldn't affect performance too much...

Comment: You can provide a fallback when canvas is not available and try not to make it too essential. I am using the same on my own page: http://abdiassoftware.com/

Comment: You could even display canvas in both cases but stop updating the canvas after the first draw (so both backgrounds will have stars) in the case of a mobile user agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the following factors is important:

- Browser, some browsers have poor canvas perf
- Device, slower devices will perform poorly, possibly affecting the whole site negatively

As stated in the comments, it's also important to consider that the background movement won't be too distracting.

With mobile devices and tablets you should be able to reasonably detect whether the device is one where you would want to run this.

On the rest, you could probably do a simple dynamic test: When the site has loaded with the animating background, run a performance test: Attempt to update the canvas as fast as possible. If you get a high enough framerate using this, you can safely assume the user's device is capable of rendering the canvas adequately. For devices where the fps is lower than expected, disable the background. You could also include a cookie for future visits which disables/enables the background automatically.

Comment: Great answer thanks will do this